# Scrollable panel make blank screen on Android

Tags: javascript, android, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I'm developing a mobile web app with Sencha Touch 2 which contains a simple panel :

```
{
    html : "....",
    height : 230,
    scrollable : true
}
```

When I do this in Android there is a scroller but all content of the panel is blank....
In iPhone there is no problem , I see the content and the scroller works.
When I remove the scrollable option from the panel I see the content , but I realy need the scroll option.

I already tried to add "fullscreen : true"

What can I do ? why the screen is blank on android when I use scrollable ?

Comment: Try to do : scrollable: {
    direction: 'vertical',
    directionLock: true
}

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the 'layout' property, and set it to 'fit', something like this:

```
{
    html : "....",
    height : 230,
    layout: 'fit',    //add this line
    scrollable : true
}
```